# How do you compare the order of two lists that contain the same elements?

Tags: python

I am trying to determine if a list is sorted the same way as another list containing the same elements. For example:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['b', 'c', 'a']

if a != b:
  print("Wrong order")
```

I want to be able to determine whether two lists have got the same ordering. It does not matter whether it is slightly different or completely, I just need to be able to tell if they are different.

Comment: If it's not sorted the same way, they *aren't equal (or identical)*. Order matters in lists; have you actually tried this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes i have, and it does not work

Comment: What is your actual question? What is the input? And what is the expected output? The above works for me as well, it prints out *Wrong order* .

Comment: @Armageddon80 well it works for me, I see *"Wrong order"*. Please give a [mcve] that actually represents your problem.

Comment: If you know that the list contains the same/equal elements simple comparision would do (if they compare different they are not sorted the same way). If you under the same assumption want to check if it contains the **same** elements in same order then `[id(x) for x in a] == [id(x) for x in b]` would do. If you wan't to verify first that they contains the same/equal elements first, then that's a different question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not entirely sure as to why it was not working for me, but after re-testing that method it worked. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Armageddon80: Some examples of desired inputs and outputs might help here.  And can you explain in what sense the code you posted "Doesn't work"?  What's your desired behaviour, and what behaviour do you actually get?

Comment: @MarkDickinson It's all resolved now, but i will remember that for next time. Thanks.

Comment: @Armageddon80 then, rather than accepting an answer that didn't actually answer the question, you should delete it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The answer i selected did help. What i was trying to solve was part of a larger thing which his answer also covered.

Comment: It might have helped you, and that's great, but it's *not an answer to the question*, because *the question itself is meaningless*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply compare sorted versions of the lists:

```
if a == b:
  print 'Same elements, same order'
elif sorted(a) == sorted(b):
  print 'Same lists, different order'
else:
  print 'Completely differeent'
```

There are of course more efficient ways to do this (e.g. you could check the lengths of the lists first...), but this is very readable.

Comment: If list a has more values than list b, it prints out 'Same lists, different order' which is incorrect since the lists are not same.

Comment: @r0xette You're right, it should be `==` instead of `!=` in the `elif` statement – I fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score -3):

I find this very pythonic:

```
different = len(set(a).difference(set(b)))
```

**UPDATE**

```
 different = len(set(a).difference(set(b))) or (len(a) != len(b))
```

Comment: This won't work if the lists contain repeated elements.

Comment: Well yes you are right but you can even additionally check the lists length to avoid this. I updated the answer

Comment: The update doesn't help. The set difference between `[1, 1, 2]` and `[1, 2, 2,]` will be null, their length the same but still they're different. In addition it doesn't differentiate between `[1, 2, 3]` and `[3, 2, 1]` which are sorted differently - which was the question. Not very pythonic to not solve the problem asked for and neither solving the problem **you** tried to solve.